# Lower Unity's resource usage on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: unity, gnome

I had Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC and I was happy with Unity 2D. I used 2D because my PC is not powerful enough to run 3D.

Now, I have installed Ubuntu 12.10, and it does not have Unity 2D.
I installed compiz-config-manager and disabled all the effects, and it is a little better now.
I wonder if there is anyway to make it a little faster?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem.
I installed gnome-classic using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Now I am running gnome-classic, and it's super fast!